# What are some guidelines for creating HTTP requests in a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, net-http

I am relatively new to writing code against REST APIs.  It is possible I am analyzing the wrong problem here, so feel free to give big picture advice.  The other twist is that the API I want to use is not yet configured, so I can't test.

I need to write some Rails code to create webhooks on the Jive API.  Jive's docs show how to register the webservice via a curl request.  I want to build the code as an admin function of my app in case we need to recreate the webhook for any reason.

Here are the [Jive Docs](https://developers.jivesoftware.com/api/v3/cloud/rest/WebhooksService.html).

Based on [this guide](https://www.socialtext.net/open/very_simple_rest_in_ruby_part_3_post_to_create_a_new_workspace), I'm thinking I need something like (I expect this example to sent a POST request to "sample.jiveon.com/api/core/v3/webhooks"):

```
@host = "sample.jiveon.com/api/core/v3"
@port = "443"

@post_ws = "/webhooks"

@payload ={
    "events" => "document",
    "callback" => "my_app/jive_listener",
    "object" => "my/jive/space"
  }.to_json

def post 
    req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(@post_ws, initheader = {'Content-Type' =>'application/json'})
      req['Authorization'] = "Bearer my_key"
      req.body = @payload
      response = Net::HTTP.new(@host, @port).start {|http| http.request(req) }
    end
end
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use gem like 'rest-client(https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client)'

Above gem does the many stuff, which you might be doing manually using bare ruby library. It depends on need of yours.